# Navigation Drawer does not move smoothly

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have created navigation drawer using sherelockActionbar libs. It is working fine and loading all fregments on available list of menus. but issue is it stops in middel when menu fragments load for few milliseconds  in a perticuler one menu  for other it moves smoothly . how to make it smooth for all menu.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try doing these fragment transactions after the navigation drawer closes completely. There is a method onDrawerClosed, where you could try to implement fragment swapping if a flag is set.

```
    navDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, navDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();

            if(makeFragmentTransaction){
               // make transaction; swap fragment
            }
        }

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
```

Just set the flag on drawer item click and after the drawer closes, it will check whether a transaction is to be made. If you decide to give it a shot, let me know how it works out for you.

Edit: updated the code.

Comment: it is for option menu but i have set custom list adapter for drawer therefore selected event receive in onclick lister of list

Comment: your solution is working but in practical scenario it is not good because in previous case navigation drawer stuck for for few milliseconds but in current scenario if fragment is a little haavy than it takes time to load so user click on menu and after few second it is reflecting so it looks bed.